# What does % of Population mean in a datasheet graphic about voltage output

Tags: datasheet, graph

I was checking a 3-axis accelerometer sensor an I found out this one https://www.digikey.it/it/datasheets/analogdevicesinc/analog-devices-inc-adxl335

Reading the datasheet, on page 6 under TYPICAL PERFORMANCE CHARACTERISTICS, all the graphics have on the Y the **% of Population**.

I can't understand what it refers to... Is it a statistic about the possible output of the sensor?

Below a screen for reference

[image: Graph]

Comment: It is a statistic graph, it show the output voltage distribution on a batch of 1000 (or more) devices. For example, 39% of the 1000 devices are a 1.51V, 32% are at 1.50V.

Comment: As I thought, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a great term they've used but '% of population' really means '% of sample group'.

They've then used the term 'n' for the where the sample group size, saying 'n > 1000' to state that the sample group is at least 1000 devices.